# IV undefined Error while decrypting AES encrypted video

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, 128-bit

I am trying to decrypt AES 128 encrypted video with AES key and IV
For decrypting I am using openssl

**key** —î¡ŒØËÉÞ°Ê¾C{]5q)pZE4d4:-MBB¬vóRJ”7–Æ­‹5•Õ
**IV** 0x496daa1c6914000e408c65cead91fc29

following is command line to decrypt video

```
openssl enc -nosalt -aes-128-cbc -d -in Question1.ts -base64 -K ^R-î^O¡ŒËÉÞ°Ê¾C^A{]5q)pZE4d4:-MBB^B¬vóR^TJ"7-Æ­‹5•Õ -iv 0x496daa1c6914000e408c65cead91fc29
```

I got this error

```
iv undefined
```

First I used AES key in command line in base64 format
and got  following error

```
hex string is too long, ignoring excess
non-hex digit
invalid hex iv value
```

then I used AES key in normal format
and got error about IV

```
iv undefined
```

Which step should be followed to decrypt video with openssl?

Comment: Sometimes the IV is prepended to the cyphertext. Try using the first block (16 bytes) of the given cyphertext as an IV and the rest as the actual cyphertext.

Comment: -K and -iv are passed incorrectly. Both options require **hex encoded** data without leading 0x, s. [*openssl enc*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html)

Comment: Regarding the key: For AES-128 the key is 16 bytes, so consists of 32 hex digits. Your key seems to be corrupted (possibly a wrong encoding).

Comment: Yep, the reason that OpenSSL is using hexadecimals is precisely because keys and IV's usually consist of random bytes, and random bytes may not represent valid or *printable* characters. So you have to use the hexadecimal representation of the bytes instead (and, indeed, without the preceding `0x` :) ). Note that I seriously doubt that OpenSSL is the best tool for the job to decrypt *a stream of data*.